# Aurelia / ES6 class and property definition, plumber syntax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am trying to get the getting started app of Aurelia to work, but I am getting an error right at the first page.
http://aurelia.io/get-started.html

The code in question :

```
export class Welcome {
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
  firstName = 'John';
  lastName = 'Doe';

  get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  welcome(){
    alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
  }
}
```

The error :

```
    [21:46:19] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError in plugin 'gulp-babel'
Message:
    D:/workspace/aurelia/navigation-app/src/app.js: Unexpected token (2:10)
  1 | export class Welcome {
> 2 |   heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
    |           ^
  3 |   firstName = 'John';
  4 |   lastName = 'Doe';
  5 |
[21:46:19] Finished 'build-system' after 20 ms
```

I have to say that I am on windows, it might create some troubles.

---

I "solved" this problem by putting the variables in a constructor. But is the syntax above not valid ES6 ? is that ES7 or something not usable yet ?

---

I know that this code looks weird but I am not the author, it is the original code from Aurelia tutorial

Comment: Not knowing how you are setup, it is hard to tell why it did not work. I built the navigation-app in windows and it worked. Maybe a problem with your dependencies.

Comment: I really followed all the instructions of the get started page. And it is only a problem of syntax that's what makes it so weird...

Comment: @sam I updated your question to give it a bit better context, if you disagree please let me know and I can undo it.  The issue is with your ES6 syntax and is not specific to Aurelia.  Make sense?

Comment: I am not sure it is ES6 but maybe directly ES7 , since this syntax is not valid in ES6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following syntax is not valid ES6 syntax for classes. BUT, it is valid ES7 property initializer syntax for classes. To use it, if you are using Babel, you need to be sure to enable this feature specifically. This is documented in the Aurelia blog and it is configured as part of the latest skeleton.

```
export class Welcome {
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
  firstName = 'John';
  lastName = 'Doe';

  get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  welcome(){
    alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I suspected, and indeed the latest skeleton works perfectly , thanks for this great framework !

Comment: so how do I enable it? I'm having same problem w/ aurelia

Comment: Your Babel options should look something like this:                module.exports = {
  modules: 'system',
  moduleIds: false,
  comments: false,
  compact: false,
  stage:2,
  optional: [ //Notice these optional ES7 features are enabled
    "es7.decorators",
    "es7.classProperties"
  ]
};

Comment: @EisenbergEffect You had told about the blog where the solution is but you didn't give the link. Could you please add it as well for the refference?

Comment: optional property does not work with babel 6. I found this [here](http://technologyadvice.github.io/es7-decorators-babel6/), but I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 1):

> But is the syntax above not valid ES6?

No it is not. Class bodies may only contain method definitions. It seems to work in experimental mode of Babel, though.

> I "solved" this problem by putting the variables in a constructor.

This is the proper solution. Data *properties* should be instance properties usually. If you want to put them on the prototype, you'll have to do that explcitly in ES6:

```
export class Welcome {
  constructor() {
    this.firstName = 'John';
    this.lastName = 'Doe';
  }

  get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  welcome(){
    alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
  }
}
Welcom.prototype.heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
```

Comment: I still wonder why the start page of Aurelia give this code, since it is supposed to be ES7 code ,then I can only guess thast it is supposed to work with their libraries ?

Comment: thias isn't a bad answer, though its also not the best answer